# Trying to analyse Azure Website Performance issue, currently have Elmah writing logs to disk, Issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, elmah, azure-web-app-service

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, EF5, SQL Azure on a Azure Websites Standard Instance.

I am suffering some performance issues, some of which are due to initial compilations ie "Cold Start".

However I am also using Elmah, and currently writing to XML files within the website. I am also getting quite a few 404 errors due to missing .ico files or references to javascript files that are not needed, but referenced. Yes I know they should not be there. However in addition to raising the 404, they raise an Elmah error. What I am trying to understand is the impact of logging to XML files , on Azure Website disk space, as opposed to a DB.

Perhaps all this disk writing could be causing locking or other issues?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue locally and use a profiler. Or, remote debug the website and pause the debugger 10 times under load. It will stop most in the slowest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used Elmah XML File error logging in at least 15 of our heavily trafficked online applications. These applications have logged millions of errors in the last 1 year. We have not faced a performance issue till date with Elmah. 
If you believe that you have a performance problem in your application, then use a profile like Ants profiler to profile your application. You should be able to find out pretty quickly what is "hot spot" in your application. We had an issue last week where a database server was down and this was causing the slowness of the application.

Comment: Ajit, thanks for this. Real world feedback is very appreciated. Any views on XML versus SQL logging regarding performance?

Comment: we have not measured the performance of XML versus SQL logging. We decided on XML based error logging because the individual xml files are easier to read, search. They can also be indexed for search by example ElasticSearch. It is pretty much the most widely used logging framework and type in our company and noone has ever suggested that we should move to xml based logging.

Comment: Thanks for this... Guess "noone has ever suggested that we should move to xml based logging" was meant to be "noone has ever suggested that we should move to sql based logging".